# Unlock an Oracle user with a batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, user-accounts, unlock

Is there a way I can write a code into a batch file that will unlock a specific account in the specified database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call SQL*Plus (as a user with permissions to unlock accounts) from within the batch file and issue the DDL to unlock the user directly from in there.

Is that the sort of answer you were looking for or have I missed something in haste?

Comment: Thank you bud. I know it is ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK; But I thought it might be different from the batch file but now I understand how stupid I was to think so

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```